# handling complex return values with - useContractRead - TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: ethers.js, wagmi

I am having a hard time handling the return values from useContractRead if my function is not a simple string or number:

Code with useContractRead in two different ways (both returning this error):

```
  const { data } = useContractRead({
    addressOrName: contractAddresses[chainId][0],
    contractInterface: abiFile,
    chainId: 4,
    functionName: "returnEndorsementsAddresses",
    args: [address],
  });

  const contractRead = useContractRead({
    addressOrName: contractAddresses[chainId][0],
    contractInterface: abiFile,
    chainId: 4,
    functionName: "viewProfile",
    args: [address],
  });
```

Solidity functions:

```
    function returnEndorsements(address _whoseThatProfile) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        uint256 a = idToOwner[_whoseThatProfile];
        endorsementList[a];
        uint256[] memory ret = new uint256[](endorsementList[a].length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < endorsementList[a].length; i++) {
            ret[i] = endorsementList[a][i];
        }
        return ret;
    }


    function viewProfileStrings(address _whoseThatProfile)
        public
        view
        returns (
            string memory username,
            string memory profilePictureUrl,
            string memory descriptionOfSkills,
            string memory resumeLink
        )
    {
        uint256 idtoreturn = idToOwner[_whoseThatProfile];
        Profile memory myProfile = profiles[idtoreturn];
        return (
            myProfile.username,
            myProfile.profilePictureUrl,
            myProfile.descriptionOfSkills,
            myProfile.resumeLink
        );
    }
```

Error Receiving

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'd'
    |     property '_readableState' -> object with constructor 'y'
    |     property 'pipes' -> object with constructor 'i'
    |     property '_readableState' -> object with constructor 'y'
    --- property 'pipes' closes the circle
```

Not sure to handle this I am not able to stringify before the function executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is possible, wish wagmis documentation would explicitly mention this. I am using ethers.js contract.methods() instead.